# Equalizer control for displaying microphone record input

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, microphone, recording, equalizer

I want to record from the microphone and while recoring, I'd like to display the current voice level like an equalizer or a wave form. It should look like a vertical progressbar which goes up and down.

Is there an existing control for this or does someone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no control per-se, but you could implement your own. You have access to the byte array for the recorded content. Given that you have the sample rate and the total content length, you can **[get the volume](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4364441/303696)** and transform it into a visual element.